# C# User Control on Mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm porting a Windows Form C# application in Linux using mono.
I'm solving a lot of problems but now I don't know what I need to do.

I can't use the User Control on linux.

I have used many user controls as container with some control
(each User Control is a button bar with some big button)
that I display when I need.

When I execute the application on linux, it does not work.

All of my User Controls (container) become transparent.
If I move the mouse I see that there is a button because the mouse cursor changes and the button responds to clicks, but it is transparent.

Comment: The sentence `When i execute the application on linux not work.` does not provide sufficient data. Please explain what does "not work" mean? Is it an exception? What do you expect to see and what do you see? Downvoting until you improve your question.

Comment: hi, thank's  for your answer.... the application start, and i know that all control are on the screen but (like already write) they are transparent..
if i move mouse where i know ther should be a button ..it change then cursor...and if i click it work...but it's all transparent..

Comment: Now I'm trying to put a few controls on-screen ..with only one User Control, it seems to work ... as I add and verify what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the User Controls but in their function paint override.
I created an override that did set some parameters of the control (size of text, syle of text) and then drew the base paint

```
public override paint(...) {
    //...instruction...
    base.paint(...);
}
```

This created problems.
Now I removed all instruction and it works.
For me this is enough. Any changes to the control do otherwise.